# Finding the upper bound of vector of pairs based on second value of pair

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pair "v" which is sorted according to the second value of the pair. Now I want to find out the upper bound of vector "v" according to the second value of the pair -- while finding the upper bound I want to ignore the first vector (`std::vector<int>`) of pair of vectors.

```
int main () {
  std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>, int> > v;           //10 10 10 20 20 20 30 30

  std::vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,10));
  a.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,10));
  a.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,10));
  a.push_back(4);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,20));
  a.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,20));
  a.push_back(6);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,20));
  a.push_back(7);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,30));
  a.push_back(8);
  v.push_back(make_pair(a,30));

  std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>, int> >::iterator low,up;
  std::vector<int> b;
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), make_pair(b,25)); 

  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin())<<" val="<<v[(up-v.begin())].second<< '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I want the upper_bound position to be returned as 6 and the value to be returned as 30. But using the above code I am incorrectly getting position as 0 and value as 10. Can someone please suggest as to how can I get the upper bound based on just the second value of the pair and ignore the first value of the pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need offer a `compare` function to `upper_bound`

---

```
template<typename T>
bool compare(const T &a,const T &b){
    return a.second<b.second;
}
```

and change:

```
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), make_pair(b,25));
```

to:

```
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), make_pair(b,25),compare<pair<vector<int>,int>>);
```

Answer (score 1):

To customize the behavior of `std::upper_bound` you can just [supply a comparison function or functor as the fourth argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).

So instead of

```
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), make_pair(b,25));
```

you'd do

```
using Pair = decltype( *v.begin() );
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), make_pair(b,25),
    []( Pair const& a, Pair const& b ) { return a.second < b.second; }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps. You can also write the comparison function  separately as shown below.

```
    auto lambda = [](const p& p1, const p& p2) {
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    };

    int idx = upper_bound(begin(v), end(v), make_pair(b, 25), lambda) - begin(v);

    cout << idx << endl;
```